# Google Sheets Script - onEdit(e) - Check if cell is a value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I make onEdit to constantly check if a specific cell is a specific value?

I would like to get an alert when a cell, which is a formula produces an error. It is an importrange and sometimes it gets 'Heavy Usage' error. So I would like onEdit to constantly check if it is not an error.

At the moment, the cell will output "Formula Works" if it detects no error or will just output the error. Whenever cell changes from "Formula Works" to the error I would like to get the alert [SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Error");].

Basically, OnEdit should be constantly checking it is "formula works" based on my every change.

This script i made did not work.

```
  var range1 = e.range;
  var spreadSheet = e.source;
  var sheetName = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var column = range1.getColumn();
  var row = range1.getRow();


  if( s.getName() == "Settings" ){
    if( range1.getRange(B6) != "Formula Works" ) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Error");
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: `This script i made did not work.` what do you mean? Is there any specific error?

Comment: @Kos It just does not give the SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Error")

Comment: onEdit triggers only fire on user edits

Comment: Your only choice is to poll for the data.  Admittedly, that's not a very attractive solution.

Comment: @Cooper I know, but i making changes constantly so it could be checking everytime if am working on the spreadsheet on every change i make.

Comment: @Cooper what do you mean by poll the data?

Comment: check it periodically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.source.getRange("SheetName!A1Notataion").getValue() == "Error Value") {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("There is an error"):
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried with `onSelectionChange(e)` but it did not work, I just replaced the onEdit with onSelectionChange, do you think you could give me a tip on this?